# how to make a function body repeat in c

Tags: c, function, loops, pointers, struct

So I am making this program and I am almost done. However, before I finish I need to make a body function repeat n times and print that answer. For example when iterated once, a string of 'duiolkjgvc' goes into this function and then becomes 'fghiwuegfvw'. Or if iterated twice, the 'fghiwuegfvw' will become whatever I coded in that function and so on.

I hope this explanation is clear, if not ask me to clarify. Any help will be appreciated.

My attempt (its a fairly long code so I will only print what is relevant to this qs):

---

```
    void printString(String * s, Rules *r);

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    ...
       printString(&s1, &r1);
    ....
}
    return 0;

void printString(String * s, Rules *r){
    if(strcmp(r->startString,p->nameReplace)==0){
          strcpy(p->newString,p->stringReplace); 
    }
}
```

so essentially, i need to repeat the function body called printString n times

Comment: Yes, very clear.

Comment: Yes, the question is clear. Where's your attempt?

Comment: whoops, sorry, i just edited the qs

Comment: Can’t you just use loop to control how many times you want to call the function?

Comment: So in the main body, i would do :  for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){  printString }?

Comment: Thats my current code right now, and it doesn't do anything :(

Comment: One problem might be that, despite its name, `printString` doesn't actually print anything.

Answer (score 3):

That should be achievable with a simple for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    doSomething();
```

A more concrete (though still contrived) example, demonstrating passing and receiving values:

```
int addOneTo(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}
:
int val = 7;
printf ("3 added to %d is: ", val);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    val = addOneTo(val);
printf("%d\n", val);
```